# Calculating charts for circle manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I've recently started learning about manifolds and I'm confused about how to calculate the charts/co-ordinate patches.  I've attached a picture for the manifold I'm working on, sorry it's drawn in pen.  I've managed to calculate what $a$ and $b$ are from arbitrary points, $x$ and $y$ on the circle (I get $a=\dfrac{2x}{1-y}$ and $b=\dfrac{2x}{1+y}$) but I don't know if this can help in calculating what $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are.  Would this simply be a case of using Pythagoras' theorem? Any help you can give me will be greatly appreciated, I realise this may be an easy answer which I've overlooked but I'm really stuck right now.  Thanks guys.

[image: Circle Manifold]

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to show that $x^2+y^2=1$ is a manifold?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Ultimately yes, but my question is how do I calculate the  charts from this manifold

Comment: It is not clear what manifold you are drawing in the picture? What's the equation?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Yeah sorry about the picture, I know it's not great.  The equation for the manifold is just a unit circle, so $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Okay. I'll give you some hints below.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using stereographic projection as you are. The first map we will construct is,

$$f: S^1 \setminus {(0,1)} \to \mathbb{R}$$

Consider the three points $(0,1), (x,y) \in S^1$ and $(u,0)$. Let $L$ be the segment that connects them. It follows that $(x,y-1) = \lambda(u,-1)$ i.e,

$$ u = u(x,y) = \frac{x}{1-y}$$

We take $f = u$. Show that this function is invertible and that both $f,f^{-1}$ are differentiable. Now we construct,

$$ g: S^1 \setminus (0,-1) \to \mathbb{R}$$

by considering the three points $(0,-1), (\tilde{x},\tilde{y}) \in S^{1}$ and $(v,0)$. Then we have $(\tilde{x},\tilde{y}+1) = \lambda (v,1)$ or in other words,

$$v = v(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})= \frac{\tilde{x}}{\tilde{y}+1}$$

We take $g = v$. Show that this function is invertible and that both $g,g^{-1}$ are differentiable. Lastly, you need to check the overlap map $f \circ g^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism as well. Note that you can also show subjectivity for completeness, but I think that is clear by construction.

Comment: OK thank you.  However, shouldn't $f$ and $g$ go from $\mathbb{R}$ into the manifold?  If so, would that change the equations for $f$ and $g$?

Comment: No. For manifolds you need charts $f_{\alpha}: M \to \mathbb{R}^{\textbf{dim}(M)}$ which are homeomorphisms who's domains cover all of $M$ and the overlap maps $f_{\alpha} \circ f_{\beta}^{-1}$ are $\mathcal{C}^k$- diffeomorphisms. Their inverses go from $\mathbb{R}$ back to the manifold.